# font size of Squirrel SQL too small

Tags: squirrel-sql

The size of the font to enter the SQL is too small. What is the way to increase the size of the font to type the SQL ?
In 'global options' there is a possibility to increase the size of the fonts. But this has no impact on the size of the text to enter the SQL.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. It looks like a perfectly valid question to me, although I'm not familiar with the tool.

Comment: The first answer above (Muhammad Usman's answer) worked for me but after making the changes in the New Session Properties I had to save my changes: File -> Save Preferences Then close and restart SQuirreL. You have to go to File -> Save Preferences pretty much any time you make any change to the settings/setup in SQuirreL.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In the **SquirreL SQL Client Version 3.7.1** you can able to increase the font size in the SQL Entry area.

Below is the procedure:

1. Go to **File --> New Session Properties**
2. Navigate to **SQL Tab** and then in the below you have the option
   called **SQL Entry Area** where you can increase your font size as
   you needed. [Click here to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxnXs.png)

Comment: I have just done a test. It is not needed to restart Squirrel to change the font size. The answer is accepted.

Comment: +1  I had been editing the session properties every time I made a new session. Thanks for saving me the annoyance.

Comment: Was looking for this. Thx!

Answer (score 16):

I'm assuming you're using Windows 8.1 like I am. It seems some combination of 8.1, high DPI monitors, and Swing don't play well together. My fix was to edit the squirrel-sql.bat file and add the following java options right after the existing java option

```
-Dswing.plaf.metal.controlFont=Tahoma-18 -Dswing.plaf.metal.userFont=Tahoma-18
```

For reference, the complete line is as follows:

```
start "SQuirreL SQL Client" /B "%LOCAL_JAVA%" -Xmx256m -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Dswing.plaf.metal.controlFont=Tahoma-18 -Dswing.plaf.metal.userFont=Tahoma-18 -cp %SQUIRREL_CP% -splash:"%SQUIRREL_SQL_HOME%/icons/splash.jpg" net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.Main %TMP_PARMS%
```

EDIT: The above will increase the size for everything except the SQL entry field. For this, go to File->New Session Properties->SQL->SQL Entry Area

Comment: I use a Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bits. It is on on a laptop not really high dpi:1600x900. I will pass the 2 parameters to the jre and report if it solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, the 2 parameters, didn't solved the problem. Everything that is displayed by the Squirrel use very big fonts (as it was configured) but the window to type the SQL uses a font that is too small (and it seems not configurable). I should look into the code.

Comment: Rudy, please let me know if you figure that part out. I've pulled down the git repo but haven't been able to figure out a way to increase the size of the SQL editor yet.

Comment: I'm using Mac OS X. I added following lines to my squirrel-sql.sh file. 
"-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Dswing.plaf.metal.controlFont=Tahoma-18 -Dswing.plaf.metal.userFont=Tahoma-18". It didn't work in my mac.

Comment: Good workaround made the app usable for me, but icons are still very small

Comment: Modifying the squirrel-sql.bat with the two font options provided by @James Freeman worked partially and fixed most of the issues for me. But the query editor still had tiny fonts, and I had to manually go into UI, `File > New Session Properties > SQL` tab, in the `SQL Entry Area`, click the `Font` button. 
Set font to Tahoma and font size to 18 (you will have to manually type in 18 as it's not available in the dropdown).

Comment: Not working for me. I have Dell XPS 9560 - 4K and the higher resolution is making  the fonts too small.

Answer (score 5):

Additional java switches on top of the ones given by James will help with other sections of the UI which shows small font.

```
-Dswing.plaf.metal.titleFont=Tahoma-18 
-Dswing.plaf.metal.menuFont=Tahoma-18 
-Dswing.plaf.metal.systemFont=Tahoma-18 
-Dswing.plaf.metal.smallFont=Tahoma-18
```

start.bat entry :

```
start "SQuirreL SQL Client" /B "%LOCAL_JAVA%" -Dsun.awt.nopixfmt=true -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Dswing.plaf.metal.controlFont=Tahoma-18 -Dswing.plaf.metal.userFont=Tahoma-18 -Dswing.plaf.metal.titleFont=Tahoma-18 -Dswing.plaf.metal.menuFont=Tahoma-18 -Dswing.plaf.metal.systemFont=Tahoma-18 -Dswing.plaf.metal.smallFont=Tahoma-18 -cp %SQUIRREL_CP% -splash:"%SQUIRREL_SQL_HOME%/icons/splash.jpg" net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.Main %TMP_PARMS%
```

[High DPI discussion on stackexchange](https://superuser.com/questions/988379/how-do-i-run-java-apps-upscaled-on-a-high-dpi-display)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what worked for me (Windows 10 64-bit, SQuirrel 3.9.1, jrw1.8.0_211)

At the bottom of `C:\Program Files\squirrel-sql-3.9.1\squirrel-sql.bat`, I changed the start command to this:

```
start "SQuirreL SQL Client" /B "%LOCAL_JAVA%"^
 -Dsun.awt.nopixfmt=true -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true^
 -Dswing.plaf.metal.controlFont=Tahoma-18^
 -Dswing.plaf.metal.userFont=Tahoma-18^
 -Dswing.plaf.metal.titleFont=Tahoma-18^
 -Dswing.plaf.metal.menuFont=Tahoma-18^
 -Dswing.plaf.metal.systemFont=Tahoma-18^
 -Dswing.plaf.metal.smallFont=Tahoma-18^
 -cp %CP%^
 -splash:"%SQUIRREL_SQL_HOME%/icons/splash.jpg"^
 net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.Main %TMP_PARMS%
```

Note, that the `^` must be at the very end of the line (no spaces after it!)

Answer (score 2):

In the `SquirreL SQL Client Version 3.9.0`:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is Font tab in the Global Preferences , there will be Four tabs, increase the Font size there, I selected Arial size 28, now my squirrel display font size large enough, so my eyes wont get strained.
File ==> Global Preferences ==> Fonts

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> New Session Properties -> SQL tab -> SQL Entry Area -> Choose FONT accordingly.

Refer to the image below:

[image: Screenshot]