# How to change the font size in Squirrel results tab?

Tags: squirrel-sql

There is an option available to change the font size of the SQL entry area as shown below.

[image: Font size]

I'm looking to modify the size of the text in the query table in **results** tab.

[image]

**Is there a separate menu available in UI to change the font sizes of the results tab?**

I'm using Squirrel v3.9.1 for macOS if that's helpful.

Not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176421/font-size-of-squirrel-sql-too-small).

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows version it's just Global Preferences + Fonts + Other